# How do I configure PyCharm to automatically and continuously run my unit tests?

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to have some background unit tests run automatically continuously.

Can this be done in PyCharm ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is very simple.  Once you have created a run configuration for the unit tests, run them once manually.  With the Run dialog open you will notice on the left hand size there are a group of icons arranged vertically.  In that group is an icon with a circular arrow.  Click that for the auto-run you seek.  It behaves smartly.  It doesn't just run continuously, but rather waits for you to make some changes in the code and for your to quiesce for a few seconds.  At that point it appears you would be done with a change and the auto-repeat fires.

[image]

Please also see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/rerunning-tests.html for some other great tips, such as only running failed tests.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful! If there is a way to get rid of that couple second wait, that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Just a comment for anyone PyCharm dumb like me. In version 4.5.4 you'll set up just as JFlo described. In the "run" window you can right click the title of the run configuration and select "Pin Tab". This will allow you to switch back to your regular "__ main __.py" run configuration and still allow tests to run continuously in the background. :-)

Comment: @jskulski I don't think so.  It appears to be intentional so as to not test while your actively making changes.  Probably not so much as to avoid slowing down the editor as much as to avoid almost certain errors if you only have half typed statements.

Answer (score 1):

I am late with answer, but here is official PyCharm documentation. The delay between your change and re-run can be decreased

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/auto-run-tests/